# address book fetching phone numbers problems

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

i was using xcode 3.2 yesterday on 10.6, I upgraded to 10.7 with xcode 4.2 the address book project which worked well in xcode 3.2, doesn't work in the new version of xcode, the following error is: (/Users/Blake/Development/g/g/ViewController.m:37:37:{37:37-37:56}{37:48-37:56}: error: cast of C pointer type 'CFStringRef' (aka 'const struct __CFString *') to Objective-C pointer type 'NSString *' requires a bridged cast [4]

```
    phones = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef peopleRecords = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

for (int i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(peopleRecords); ++i)
{
    ABRecordRef recordRef = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(peopleRecords, i);
    ABMultiValueRef phoneRefs = ABRecordCopyValue(recordRef, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    for (int a = 0; a < ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneRefs); ++a)
    {
        CFStringRef phoneStr = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneRefs, a);
        NSString* phoneString = (NSString*)phoneStr;
        [phones addObjectphoneString];
        CFRelease(phoneStr);
    }

    CFRelease(phoneRefs);
}

CFRelease(addressBook);
CFRelease(peopleRecords);

for (NSString *phone in phones)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", phone) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it like this:

```
//get all phone numbers                   
ABMultiValueRef phoneNumberProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(currentPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
NSArray *phoneNumbersArray = (NSArray*)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(phoneNumberProperty);
```

Then I iterate the phoneNumbersArray for NSString.